# MySQL querying products from one table only if they appear in certain category table

Tags: sql, mysql, sorting

I've got the following tables:

```
Products:
  id, name, ...

Products_in_Categories
  id, category_id, product_id

Categories
  id, name, ...
```

I have an admin page where I want to let him search products by name, catalog id etc. And of course by category and name and catalog id ...

So without the category - it's really easy. But when I want the search to be able to extract only the information of the products that are related to the chosen category - I just can't figure it out.

Am I using some old methods or is this the way to store it? I know and have used serialize and unserialize but I didn't want to use it here.

Any help will be very appreciated, thank you!

Comment: what's the role of catalog? is it the same as category?

Comment: it's not the same, it's just a user custom input field (varchar).

Comment: I reformatted your question, hope that's ok for you.

Comment: I think you should start by learning `SQL` if you would like to answer such questions, this question is not `MySQL`-specific. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207716/what-is-the-best-sql-book-or-web-tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the way you store your products, these three tables are the right way to store that sort of relation.

```
SELECT *
FROM Categories c
JOIN Products_in_Categories pic ON ( pic.category_id = c.category_id )
JOIN Products p ON ( p.id = pic.product_id )
WHERE c.name = 'YOUR_CATEGORY_NAME';
```

Replace `YOUR_CATEGORY_NAME` by the category name you search for. If you want the user to be able to enter just a part of the name, replace `WHERE c.name = 'YOUR_CATEGORY_NAME';` by

```
WHERE c.name LIKE '%CATEGORY_NAME_PART%;
```

Comment: Thank you!
wow! it worked great!
Thank you very much - I gotta study this field more in depth.
Do you have any good suggestion for a mysql book ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.* FROM products as p
LEFT JOIN Products_in_Cateogries pc ON pc.product_id = p.id,
LEFT JOIN Categories c ON c.id = pc.categroy_id
WHERE c.name = 'CATEGORY A'
```

you also don't need to have a id in the Products_in_Categories table since the combination of category_id and product_id is unique.

Comment: Thanks.
I can't really understand this query, but I will dig more for what you wrote. when I used it "as is" it said I have error, do I need to change anything besides CATEGORY A ?